# Config file for Mobile apps - HTML/Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, mobile

I am creating a mobile application using PhoneGap and HTML5. I'd like setup configurable values such as server name etc into it's separate file (similar to a `App.config` or `Web.config` in a ASP.NET application).

I know HTML5 supports some storage mechanisms such as WebSQL etc. Should I be using one of these?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about config in a js file?
Just like app.ServerName=""

Answer (score 0):

It easier to and modify HTML 5 local Storage like below

```
    // Store
 localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

sources tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

If you like reading file you can use the reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs read here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/